# UILabels NOT Updating

Tags: core-data, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a `UITableView` that is being populated by core data. Now, when I click on a cell, it pushes me to another view where I can edit the data that is in that particular index, when I return, the system either crashes or else doesn't load the changes onto the labels, any ideas? code below

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{    
    searchCriteria = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"clientName"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"clientName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];    
    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

    [self.clientTableView reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];    
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Client * client = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    clientNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 250.00, 30.0)];
    clientNameLabel.tag = 1;
    clientNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    clientNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    clientNameLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    clientNameLabel.text = client.clientName;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:clientNameLabel];

    clientAccountNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 35.0, 250.00, 30.00)];
    clientAccountNumberLabel.tag = 2;
    clientAccountNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    clientAccountNumberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    clientAccountNumberLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    clientAccountNumberLabel.text = client.clientAccountNumber;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:clientAccountNumberLabel];

    clientTelephoneNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300.0, 0.0, 250, 30.00)];
    clientTelephoneNumberLabel.tag = 3;
    clientTelephoneNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    clientTelephoneNumberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    clientTelephoneNumberLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:clientTelephoneNumberLabel];

    addressLine1Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
    addressLine1Label.tag = 4;
    addressLine1Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addressLine1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    addressLine1Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    addressLine1Label.text = client.addressLine1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine1Label];

    addressLine2Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
    addressLine2Label.tag = 5;
    addressLine2Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addressLine2Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    addressLine2Label.text = client.addressLine2;
    addressLine2Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine2Label];

    addressLine3Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
    addressLine3Label.tag = 6;
    addressLine3Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addressLine3Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    addressLine3Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    addressLine3Label.text = client.addressLine3;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine3Label];

    addressLine4Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
    addressLine4Label.tag = 7;
    addressLine4Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addressLine4Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    addressLine4Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
    addressLine4Label.text = client.addressLine4;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine4Label];

    return cell;
}
```

The Crash Logs are as follows:

```
2012-06-23 17:08:05.541 iSalesForce[11773:15803] no object at index 1 in section at index 0
```

And some other code you might find useful are:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [fetchedObjects count];
}

- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70.0;
}
```

Comment: tl;dr -- what's the actual crash you are getting?  show a backtrace.

Comment: show the code for your "`numberOfSectionsInTableView:`" method, too.

Comment: Don't put these things into comments, which are hard for me (or anyone else) to read.  Edit your original question and put in these additional methods and the crash log / backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the fact your fetchedResultsController has gone stale (are you using ARC? is that fetchedResultsController a "`strong`" property?

Or it may simply be that your fetchedResultsController has no objects and you're insisting that you have exactly one object in your "`numberOfSectionsInTableView`" method, regardless of the true contents of "`fetchedResultsController`".

Try this new & improved function:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        // this should never happen, but just in case...
        NSLog( @"cell is still - unexpectedly - nil" );
    } else {
        if(self.fetchedResultsController == nil)
        {
            NSLog( @"surprise, fetchedResultsController is nil" );
        } else {
            Client * client = nil;
            @try {
                client = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                NSLog( @"exception thrown while trying to fetch something from fetchedResultsController - %@ %@", [e name], [e reason] );
            }
            @finally {
                clientNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 250.00, 30.0)];
                clientNameLabel.tag = 1;
                clientNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                clientNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                clientNameLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                clientNameLabel.text = client.clientName;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:clientNameLabel];

                clientAccountNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 35.0, 250.00, 30.00)];
                clientAccountNumberLabel.tag = 2;
                clientAccountNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                clientAccountNumberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                clientAccountNumberLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                clientAccountNumberLabel.text = client.clientAccountNumber;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:clientAccountNumberLabel];

                clientTelephoneNumberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300.0, 0.0, 250, 30.00)];
                clientTelephoneNumberLabel.tag = 3;
                clientTelephoneNumberLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                clientTelephoneNumberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                clientTelephoneNumberLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:clientTelephoneNumberLabel];

                addressLine1Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
                addressLine1Label.tag = 4;
                addressLine1Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                addressLine1Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                addressLine1Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                addressLine1Label.text = client.addressLine1;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine1Label];

                addressLine2Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
                addressLine2Label.tag = 5;
                addressLine2Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                addressLine2Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                addressLine2Label.text = client.addressLine2;
                addressLine2Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine2Label];

                addressLine3Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
                addressLine3Label.tag = 6;
                addressLine3Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                addressLine3Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                addressLine3Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                addressLine3Label.text = client.addressLine3;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine3Label];

                addressLine4Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(315.0, 35.0, 250, 30.00)];
                addressLine4Label.tag = 7;
                addressLine4Label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                addressLine4Label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                addressLine4Label.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
                addressLine4Label.text = client.addressLine4;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:addressLine4Label];

            }

            Client * client = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

(I didn't actually test this out... but I did put some new error checking and exception handling into it for you)

Comment: But why would it do that , [FetchedObjects count] has data in it , that is whats frustrating me !

Comment: OK !! That worked out perfectly , one small thing , why is it that when i update change the value in another view controller and then come back to this view the data doesnt change ? it doesnt make sense because i have the searching code in the -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)Animated method

Comment: Probably because you haven't explicitly told the table to "`reloadData`".  One place to put it is in your parent view controller's "`viewWillAppear:`" method.

Comment: Solved it , Will post as soon as it lets me upload my own answer :D

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 is the answer